# Highcharts PIE chart series color doesn't change

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

Pie charts series color doesn't work on my angularjs application. It selects some predefined colors (as seen in image). But when I try to recreate the issue on jsfiddle it works as expected.

here is the working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gmwbck5q/1

this is the angularjs component definition:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('comp.components')
        .component('dashboardHcChart', {
            template: '<div></div>',
            controller: DashboardHCChart,
            bindings: {
                chartConfig: '<'
            }
        });

    function DashboardHCChart($element) {

        this.$onInit = () => {
            Highcharts.chart($element[0], this.chartConfig);
        };
    }
})();
```

here is what i get with the same code on my angularjs application:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/btcAD.jpg

Comment: Could you prepare a package with a simplified app and instructions on how to run it? Then it will be possible to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what was the problem.
I've imported the highcharts SCSS file to my project:

```
@import "node_modules/highcharts/css/highcharts.scss";
```

and I'm guessing this was overwriting the configuration I was providing to each chart. (Am I correct?)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer solution here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishk3499/04ndh15e/2/). [image]

There might be some error with your `chartConfig` object.

Comment: if there was a problem in ```chartConfig``` it wouldn't work on jsfiddle as well since it's the same.

Comment: You can check the jsFiddle above, I use angularJs component structure like you mentioned in problem

Comment: I copied and paste the config you set and I still get the black/green/blue colors on my chart on my angularjs application :(

Comment: Can you share your config object or try `series data` as

 `"series": [{
      "name": "Total Alerts",
      "colorByPoint": true,
      "data": [{
        "name": "High",
        "y": 13401,
        "total": 13401,
        "color": "#e87e04"
      }]
}]`

Comment: is the problem with static data or with dynamic data from api? @KfirM

Comment: It's only static data.

Comment: Are you getting some error in console? and without looking into your code. It is hard to tell where the error is.

Comment: No errors in console.The code I posted is the same as in my application. If I could I would post the entire application. I think It doesn't show any errors since it does work, just not with the right colors.

Comment: Can you try configuration as in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishk3499/04ndh15e/7/)